# c# Update LED component from everywhere

Tags: c#, sql, multithreading, user-interface

I have a question related to a simple task: update the control status from any class in the namespace. 
In detail I have written a GUI that opens different forms from listbox (each row opens a different form). In some cases the form called has to retrieve data from SQL database, in this kind of scenario I'd like to insert a couple of custom controls (LED) in order to signal to the user when the system is retrieving data (RED LED) or is ready (GREEN LED).

Basically the result is that I'm not able to update these controls during the form loading, I have noticed that a good way can be the backgroundworker but not sure if it is right.

Do you have any idea how to manage it?

Comment: Are you talking WinForms?  WPF?  Something else?  You should generally be able to update controls during the form load event.  What specific problem are you encountering?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would need to use a `BackgroundWorker` or some other asynchronous operation. If you do your logic during `FormLoad`, which is a synchronous operation, you won't see any updates in your form no matter what.

So, for example with a background worker:

```
BackgroundWorker bw;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true; //allows call backs
    bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
    bw.ProgressChanged += bw_ProgressChanged;

    bw.RunWorkerAsync(); //run the worker
}

void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var message = e.UserState;
    //do something with the UserState on the UI, like flash a light
}

void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker localBW = (BackgroundWorker)sender;

    //do your logic here, when you want to "report progress"
    //use the following lines
    localBW.ReportProgress(0, "hey, flash please"); // or something else

    //when you are all done, you can pass something back
    e.Result = "I'm done now";
}
```

For more reading, see the [msdn page on BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx), a ["How to:" using a BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx), and [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await (a newer topic with .net 4.0 and up)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. My attention is on your sentence:

If you do your logic during FormLoad, which is a synchronous operation, you won't see any updates in your form no matter what.

Are you meaning that there is no way to update a control during a form_load?

Comment: First, anything done inside `FormLoad` will happen before the form will be shown to the user. Second, say you make a button handler method. You click the button which runs the following 3 items in a line: 1 - display text to a label, 2 - wait 3 seconds, 3 - display a different text. Because of how synchronous operations work, you won't see the first label text. You need to make is async for that to work.

Comment: Really clear, in fact I lose the first status. So, if I correctly understood, I need to light RED led (busy status) BEFORE loading form (during the SelectIndexChanged is ok?), wait the end of the loading and than light GREEN led (ready status)? Am I right? Thank you very much for help

Comment: I would turn on the green light when your background worker has completed (runs the `RunWorkerCompleted` event). Otherwise sounds good, try it out!